# Using SQL Variables as Column Headers with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic-sql

I have a pretty long stored procedure (in SQL Server) where a business user asked if it would be possible to rename columns with values that are being stored in declared variables.

Here are variables declared at top of stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate  datetime = '12/31/23';
DECLARE @PlusBeginDate datetime = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @BeginDate);
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, 120, EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @PlusBeginDate)));
DECLARE @IncludePaidPortion bit = 0;
DECLARE @MonthAnnual char = 'M';
DECLARE @FinanceCompany varchar(max) = '1';
DECLARE @IncludeOnStream bit = 0;
DECLARE @TranCode varchar(max) = '1,35';
DECLARE @ContractBookType varchar(max) = 'capital';
DECLARE @FinanceProduct varchar(max) = '1,2,3';
DECLARE @IncludedStatus varchar(max) = '0';
DECLARE @IncludeTerminated bit = 0;
DECLARE @FundingSource varchar(max) = '0';
DECLARE @FinanceProgram varchar(max) = '20734';
DECLARE @ADC varchar(max) = '0';
DECLARE @IncludeResidual bit = 0;
```

It is apart of a larger stored procedure but here is what I have in regards to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CaseDate datetime = '12/31/9999';

SET @sqlQuery = '
    SELECT
        MAX(ContractId) as ContractId,
        MAX([Maturity Date]) as [Maturity Date],
        MAX([Extended Maturity Date]) as [Extended Maturity Date],
        @PlusBeginDate AS ReportBegin,
        @EndDate AS ReportEnd,
        SUM(PeriodCash1) as [' + QUOTENAME(@PeriodValue1) + '],
        SUM(PeriodCash2) as [' + QUOTENAME(@PeriodValue2) + ']
    FROM
                    (SELECT 
                        Cash.ContractOid
                        ,Cash.TransactionCodeOid
                        ,Cash.DueDate
                        ,ISNULL(Contract.ContractId,''N/A'') as ContractId
                        ,lc.AccountDistributionCodeOid
                        ,ContractTerm.MaturityDate as [Maturity Date]
                        ,CASE
                            WHEN ContractTerm.MaturityDate <> lc.[Maturity Date] 
                                THEN lc.[Maturity Date] 
                            ELSE ''''
                        END as [Extended Maturity Date]
                        ,CASE 
                            WHEN DueDate BETWEEN @PeriodBegin1 AND @PeriodEnd1 
                            AND DueDate <= ISNULL(Contract.TerminationDate,@CaseDate)
                                THEN Amount
                            ELSE 0  
                        END AS PeriodCash1      
                        ,CASE 
                            WHEN DueDate BETWEEN @PeriodBegin2 AND @PeriodEnd2
                            AND DueDate <= ISNULL(Contract.TerminationDate,@CaseDate)
                                THEN Amount
                            ELSE 0  
                        END AS PeriodCash2      
                    FROM #Cash Cash
                    INNER JOIN #LimitedContracts lc on lc.ContractOid = Cash.ContractOid
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Contract ON Cash.ContractOid = Contract.ContractOid
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.ContractTerm ON ContractTerm.ContractOid = Contract.ContractOid AND ContractTerm.IsPrimary = 1
                    inner join dbo.Product p on p.oid = ContractTerm.ProductOid
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity FinComp ON FinComp.oid = Contract.CompanyOid   
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity On Entity.oid = Contract.EntityOid  
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Status ON Status.oid = Contract.StatusOid
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TransactionCode ON TransactionCode.TransactionCodeOid = Cash.TransactionCodeOId
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.AccountDistributionCode ADC ON ADC.AccountDistributionCodeOid = lc.AccountDistributionCodeOid
                    ) SubQuery
            GROUP BY SubQuery.ContractOid, SubQuery.TransactionCodeOid
            ORDER BY ContractID';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
```

For some reason it is returning the following errors:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
> Must declare the scalar variable "@PlusBeginDate".
>
> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 8
> The identifier that starts with '[January 2024],
> SUM(PeriodCash2) as [[February 2024]
> FROM
> (SELECT
> C' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

As you can see `PlusBeginDate` is declared, and this error does not occur if I only run everything prior to the dynamic SQL.

The length error doesn't make much sense either, as each variable is as follows: "MONTH YYYY" never comes close to 128 characters.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't passing those variables to your dynamic statement as parameters , and you don't `DECLARE` them in the dynamic statement, so the behaviour is expected.

Comment: `[' + quotename(@PeriodValue) + ']` is going to give you weird results. `quotename` takes care of wrapping the value in square brackets. What you have is going to do that twice.

Comment: What did you notice when you `print`ed your `@sqlQuery` ? - Oh, and two digit years?!! Tip, define your dates unambiguously as YYYYMMDD

Comment: @ThomA How do I go about passing them through into the dynamic sql? Every example I've seen on here they don't declare within the dynamic. Please provide example if possible, thank you!!! And its weird an error doesnt occur with the other variables towards the top of my dynamic query?

Comment: Just to reiterate, you are getting the error about the identifier being too long because you're basically injection attacking yourself. `quotename` escapes the `[` character to `[[` but since you are then wrapping the whole statement in another set of quotes, it's trying to treat _the rest of your sql_ as part of the column name (hence: "The identifier ...is too long"). Remove the square brackets around your `[' + quotename(@PeriodValue) + ']`

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  explains and shows how to pass variables using sp_executesql

Comment: @Xedni I removed quotename as I did not realize its purpose (just adds brackets). could this be an issue with not declaring the variables inside the dynamic sql query?

Comment: It is much better practice (read: safer) to use `QUOTENAME()` and _not_ append your own square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two separate, and unrelated errors here, so I'll discuss each in turn.

The first error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6 Must declare the scalar variable "@PlusBeginDate".

This is because you are using a variable declared *outside* the scope of the dynamic SQL, but it's not being provided *to* the dynamic SQL. When you call [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) you have to pass in those parameters explicitly, or else it's just like they were never declared.

So for your example, your call to `sp_executesql` should look something like

```
exec sp_exceutesql
    @sqlQuery,
    -- Variables you use within your dynamic sql
    N'@PeriodBegin1 date,
        @PeriodBegin2 date,
        @PlusBeginDate...
        ... <all other variables you are using within your dynamic sql',
    -- Variables outside your dynamic sql you want passed into your dynamic sql
    @PeriodBegin1,
    @PeriodBegin2,
    @PlusBeginDate...
    ... 
    /*
    <all the variables you want to pass into the procedure. use the same order as how you
    defined them in your parameters block>
    */
```

That will get the first error to go away by making your dynamic sql have those values in scope.

The second error:

> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 8 The identifier that starts with '[January 2024], SUM(PeriodCash2) as [[February 2024] FROM (SELECT C' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

This is happening because you aren't quoting your `@PeriodValue` correctly. The correct syntax is `' + quotename(@PeriodValue) + '` *not* `[' + quotename(@PeriodValue) + ']`. The way `quotename` works for square brackets is by escaping (i.e. doubling) all left square brackets within your string, the wrapping the resulting statement in square brackets. However since you are manually adding *another* level of square brackets around the outside, you're re-opening your column name brackets, and never closing them. Hence, it's treating all the subsequent SQL after your `quotename` section as part of the column alias. And since a column name can't exceed 128 characters, it's throwing that error.

TL;DR, remove those extra square brackets around that `quotename` and I think that should be fixed as well.

Comment: I created a @ParamDef, where I list each variable and its datatype. 

As well in the execute I list out eachvariable that is being called.

Comment: And get these errors in return:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 371
Incorrect syntax near '2024'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1202
Incorrect syntax near 'SubQuery'.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your new code. There are two things I would recommend doing. First, as mentioned in the comments on your original question, learn to love `print @sqlQuery`. It can be very difficult to tell where your dynamic sql is going awry when everything is all red. Pasting the results in a query window will often show you exactly where your problem is. Second, if that doesn't work, try to replicate your problem using a smaller, toy example. e.g. if you get rid of your whole subquery, do you till have those errors? That can tell you where to focus

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not just helpful for getting help on StackOverflow, it's also a really powerful technique for solving your own problems. I can't tell you how many times I've been about to ask a question on SO, and I try to distill it down to the minimum example people would need to help me, and in so doing, I found exactly where my problem lay.